# how to create separate war for my front end (angularjs) in multimodule maven project

Tags: angularjs, maven, spring-mvc, maven-3, war

I am using this directory structure :

```
Parent
 | 
 |--Back-end(one module FOR enitity)
 |   |- pom.xml
 |
 |--Back-end(one module FOR rest)
 |   |- pom.xml
 |
 |--Back-end(one module FOR service)
 |   |- pom.xml
 |
 |--Front-end(module for angular)
 |   |-public
 |   |    |-myApp
 |   |        |-all angularjs related files
 |   
 |
 |
 |pom.xml
```

---

My back-end module produces a WAR but now how to make separate war for angular : the goal here is to be able to deploy the entire javascript application(angularjs) as a java war file.

Comment: Why does the back-end module produce a WAR? I'd expect a normal JAR that you can add as a dependency to `Front-end`..

Comment: the goal here is to be able to deploy the entire javascript application (angularjs ) as a java war file to make it easier to deploy, so I want to have two war files the rest.war and the webjs.war

Comment: I don't see where you get `rest.war` from.

Comment: i m using in rest module : <groupId>com.org</groupId>
 <artifactId>mp-rest</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>

Comment: Why do you want the code from `mp-rest` in `webjs.war`? Shouldn't the JS frontend connect to the REST server via the REST api?

Comment: yes...now i want to make separate war for angular

Comment: Maven doesn't stop you from having two modules with `packaging=war`. What exactly is your problem? Do you have an error?

Comment: no dont have error ..ok i m making that module using packaging=war. thnx a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `<packaging>jar</packaging>` for all modules. Then create two new modules which have `<packaging>war</packaging>` and which depend on the plain JARs created by the other modules.

That way, you can reuse the Java code in your WARs. If you want to share files below `WEB-INF`, then you can create a common WAR module for that and use [WAR overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html). This means you have many modules which produce JARs and three that produce WARs. Note that WAR overlays are somewhat brittle, so it's often better to stay away from them.