# Generating war file from Angularjs project

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular JS. I had developed an Angular Js project and my project folder structure will be like

```
 images
 |
 modules
 |
 scripts
 |
 styles
 |
 index.html
```

I don't know how to get a war file out of the developed Angular project.

Could some throw some light on how to or any online sources available to the understanding?

NOTE: this question is not for researching.

I surfed through a search engine and got to know tools like grunt bower but I don't know how to use them. Any help from Angular experts, I would be grateful.

Comment: Create a Maven project in eclipse and put your Folder in webapp folder. Build the project, Your war is created.

Comment: You sure, you are using Java ?

Comment: Additinally go through this link - http://csetutorials.com/deploy-angular-2-maven-webapp-on-tomcat.html

Comment: @yashpandey thanks a lot.. i am using for the webservices and the businesslogic the front end is angular js that would call rest services. the businesslogic war is deployed in jboss so my objective to generate war of this angular proj and deploy it in the jboss

Comment: so you are actually using maven. The point is starting the angular app, and i think you need angular plugins in the link given above!

Comment: @yashpandey actually the UX is separately developed i need to get a war file out of it

Comment: Then this one is best for you .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145394/how-to-create-separate-war-for-my-front-end-angularjs-in-multimodule-maven-pro